# Passing array of pointers into a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void getline(char *line, int lim)
{
    int len = 0;
    char c;
    while (len < lim)
    {
        if ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        {
            *line++ = c;
            printf("reading %c\n", c);
            len++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    *line = '\0';
}


int main()
{
    char (*lines)[500]; // pointer to array with 500 chars
    char *linetwo[4]; //why doesnt this work????  array of 4 pointers.


    getline(*lines, 500);
    getline(*linetwo, 500); // !!!!ERROR!!!

    printf("%s", *lines);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

I'm having trouble with this code. I want four lines of input with each lines having maximum 500 chars. I wrote a **getline** function to save it to a char * pointer. However, **getline** gives error when I initialize an array of pointers.

The only difference between `(*lines)[500]` and `*lines[4]` is, I think, whether it does not specify either the number of lines or the number of chars in a line.

Please help me understand why passing *linetwo into getline after *linetwo[4] initialization gives error.

Comment: You're dereferencing two *indeterminate* pointers, sending the results to a function that expects valid memory on which to write. You program thus invokes *undefined behavior* in every case where `*lines` or `*linetwo` appears as expressions.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't quite understand your comment :( I'm a beginner, so can you plz elaborate what it means to dereference two indeterminate pointers??

Comment: @BLUEPIXY How are they incorrect??

Comment: Neither of the pointers your sending to `getline` actually point to valid memory. *That's* what I mean. Your code declares something that *can* point to an array of 500 `char` (but doesn't), and a array of four pointers, each of which *can* point to `char` data of indeterminate length (but none do). In short, *neither* of the pointer values you're sending to `getline` actually point to anything concrete, yet `getline` treats them as if they do (because you told it so).

Comment: @deNsuh Please allocate memory should point by pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for your answer, it's helpful a lot :) but one more question; why does then getline(*lines, 500) work? Does the compiler somehow allocate memory to 500 undetermined chars?

Comment: @deNsuh No, no allocation takes place (which is part of the problem). Posted answer below, best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pointers don't point to anything, yet you use them as if they do. This is closer to what you likely need.

```
int main()
{
    char (*lines)[500] = malloc(sizeof *lines);
    char *linetwo[4] = { malloc(500) }; // other three pointers will be NULL

    getline(*lines, sizeof *lines);
    getline(*linetwo, 500); // or linetwo[0]

    printf("%s", *lines);
    system("PAUSE");

    free(lines);
    free(linetwo[0]);
    return 0;    
}
```

Note: no error checking performed above. Use at your own discretion. Also note your `getline` may-well conflict with the POSIX library function [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), which is a different issue entirely.

Comment: thanks a lot! I now kind of get the idea of memory allocating and dereferencing and stuff :)

Comment: @deNsuh so long as you understand the difference between a pointer to an array of length N (`lines` in your code), and an array of length N of pointers (`linetwo` in your code), you'll probably be ok. Its a hurdle for beginning C programmers. Keep at it.

Comment: Not a beginner but still learning. I had thought the two `char` declarations were synonymous (apart from the `500` and the `4`). But when I print the `sizeof` each one, they are `4` and `16`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah, they're not synonymous, as you can see. One declares *a* pointer (singular) to type `char[500]`, the other declares an array of four pointers (plural) to a specific type `char`. As I said, it's part of the set of hurdles beginners have to get over when learning C, pointers, etc. It can certainly be confusing at-first, to be sure.

Comment: After 25 years or so I still would not use `char (*lines)[500]`, I would keep it simple and use `char *line` in the singular. Since `getline()` doesn't know the length, without the additional argument, what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

```
char * lines[10];
```

Declares and allocates an array of pointers to `char`. Each element must 
be dereferenced individually.

```
char (* lines)[10]; /* invalid until assigned or malloc'ed) */
```

Declares (without allocating) a pointer to an array of `char`('s). The 
pointer to the array must be dereferenced to access the value of each 
element.

Answer (score 0):

To pass array of pointers in the function just pass the array name without using '*'

and that changes your function declaration with

```
void getline(char *line[], int lim)
```

and calling with

```
getline(linetwo, 500);
```

This is the easiest way to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
void getline(char *line, int lim)
```

This function expects a pointer.

You are passing array of pointer to it (`*linetwo[4]`) .Thus give an error.

To pass `*linetwo[4]` to pass this you can do this

```
void getline(char **line, int lim)
```